# JQuery remove first item from ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list that I am prepending data to as follows:

```
jQuery("#mylist").prepend(newItem);
```

When the list reaches a certain size I need to remove the first item that was inserted before adding the new one.

How would I get the first item to remove based on accessing the ordered list by it's id.

Something like:

```
 jQuery("#mylist")[0].remove();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you mentioned ordered list, im assuming #mylist contains li tags inside, thus this should work

```
jQuery("#mylist li:first-child").remove();
```

I see you are prepending there, In case you want to remove the last element then

```
jQuery("#mylist li:last-child").remove();
```

Comment: Perfect response. Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers mate

Comment: @JIbber4568: Can you tell us which of the two is correct to clear a discussion in another answer?

Comment: `jQuery("#mylist li:first-child").remove()` will remove the top most element from the list where as `jQuery("#mylist li:last-child").remove()` will remove the bottom most element in the list. Since you are using prepend to add a new element, in that case I believe your latest elements are going on top, thus `jQuery("#mylist li:last-child").remove();` would remove the first element that was added at the bottom.

Comment: @atif089: ??? I know what your solution is about. But I would like to know which of the two was actually the helpful one to OP (not you). His question is ambiguous because he asks twice and each question has a different meaning: **1.** *remove the first item that was inserted* (which matches last child) and **2.** *How would I get the first item to remove based on accessing the ordered list* (which matches first child).

Comment: `jQuery("#mylist li:last-child").remove();` was what I needed as I needed to remove the first element that had been inserted into the list but was effectively the last item on page. Cheers

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: ^^^---Sweet, sweet victory. **;-)**

Comment: @user1689607: you just made me laugh and feel great. Thanks mate. :) great comment! :D :D :D

Comment: @JIbber4568: what can you learn from this? That your question wasn't really clear so it could be interpreted one way or the other. I suggest that **next time you make yourself more clear** so there won't be any disambiguation. This has two implications: it makes our work easier and you get your correct answer quicker.

Comment: or could lead by your example and go on about it in the comments for almost 24 hours... the answers been marked and votes cast.... so why bother keep going on about it.  Besides you didn't even put an answer why does it matter to you?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing `.prepend()`, the *first* item inserted would be the last item in the list, so you'd do this:

```
$("#mylist").children().last().remove();
```

Comment: That's not how jQuery traverses DOM. Even if first child has been inserted as last one it will still be **first** in DOM and jQuery will see it as **first** and not as last as you imply...

Comment: @down-voter: The OP doesn't say to remove the first item in the list. It says to remove the first item that was inserted, which would be the last in the list, assuming the list started off empty.

Comment: @user1689607: That's a bit doubious statement from the OP. I would think your answer would be correct if OP would say: *When the list reaches a certain size I need to remove previously inserted before adding the new one.* I'm not sure he meant it this way because you were apparently the only one to understand it this way. Everyone else understood it as removing the first child. But even though. He's adding items to the top so it always removes first child which is the same as previously prepended item.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: This doesn't remove the previously inserted on. It removes the first one that was inserted. Because of `.prepend()`, the oldest ones are at the end of the list,.

Comment: "the first item that was inserted" seems clear to me. I'm upvoting this answer.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Notice that the answer you previously endorsed has been updated to effectively match the behavior in my answer.

Comment: @destroy: you may as well be correct. I wanted to remove my downvote but I'm not able to unless this answer is edited...

Comment: @user1689607: Still that person is not providing one answer only but since question is ambiguous one of his solution is correct. My upvote there still stands. If you edit your answer I will remove my downvote because it may be that you're right and I was wrong.

Comment: @user1689607 I did knew that but I thought to answer first and then edit due to the ambiguity of the question. You have my upvote anyways :-) cheers!

Comment: Can't do both you know. I can't remove my downvote until your answer is edited and I can up and downvote the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `[0]` is the same as `get(0)` which is selecting the DOM element. The DOM does not have `.remove()`. Plus you are selecting the parent element and not the children.

You can use eq(0) to select the first

```
 jQuery("#mylist li").eq(0).remove();
```

there are other jQuery selectors/methods such as .first(), :first, :first-child